# iPhone - NSTimer not repeating after fire

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I am creating and firing a `NSTimer` with:

```
ncTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleTimer:)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:YES];
[ncTimer fire];
```

AND

```
- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)chkTimer {
    // do stuff
}
```

I am retaining my timer with:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *ncTimer;
```

For some reason the timer is not repeating. It is firing once only and than never again.

Comment: *A stupid question on my part, but it's best to be sure:* I presume you're not invalidating the timer anywhere inside the handleTimer method?

Comment: No I am not.. the only thing I have to add is that I am firing the timer in the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just assign to the timer that you have put as a property in your header. This should work:

```
self.ncTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

Also: The fire method fires the timer, out of cycle. If the timer is non repeating it is invalidated. After the line that says fire, add this:

```
BOOL timerState = [ncTimer isValid];
NSLog(@"Timer Validity is: %@", timerState?@"YES":@"NO");
```

Comment: "Timer Validity is: YES" but still no luck... the timer is not repeating. What could be the problem here?

Comment: I just made a little test app to see what happened and it worked fine for me with the self. Do you have the @synthesize ncTimer at the top of your implementation?

Comment: Yeah i got that... I have done this in many other apps and its worked fine so I can't figure out whats wrong here

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I was starting the timer in a method called from another class in a separate thread which does not allow the timer to repeat.

Comment: so how can we handle this? How can repeat NSTimer can work from another class?

Comment: @VaibhavSaran check my answer at this same question

Comment: but I have replied also, see below :)

Answer (score 39):

The `-fire:` method manually fires it once. For a timer to be started and repeat, you have to add it to a runloop using `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: forMode:]`

Comment: This is correct, but it's simpler to use the `NSTimer` `scheduleTimerWith...` methods instead of manually adding to the run loop.

Answer (score 29):

Got it

Adding timer to `mainRunLoop` made it working

Here you go:

Objective C:

```
self.ncTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

**Swift 2**

```
var ncTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("handleTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(ncTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
var ncTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.handleTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(ncTimer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
```

Comment: Wouldn't Objective C be `NSTimer *ncTimer` instead of `self.ncTimer`? Also, wouldn't you say `addTimer:ncTimer` instead of `addTimer:timer`? I have the power to edit this, but I wanted you to be aware of what needed to be done.

Comment: Me too, this worked for me but `scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval` didn't

Comment: In swift 4: `RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)`

Answer (score 8):

You can also copy your code inside this block, which inserts the creation of the Timer in the main thread.

The code will therefore remain:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  self.ncTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why but Timer.scheduledTimer method is not working but Timer.init method worked.

```
self.timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 10.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            print("\n--------------------TIMER FIRED--------------\n")
            self.checkForDownload()
        })
RunLoop.main.add(self.timer!, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assigning to `ncTimer` as you have will not initiate the properties `retain` functionality.

Assuming the declaration is within the member object you will need to do:

```
self.ncTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]
```

Comment: I added self. but the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

You could write the same thing in **Swift** without running in main loops by:

```
ncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, 
                               target: self, 
                               selector: #selector(self.handleTimer), 
                               userInfo: nil, 
                               repeats: true)
ncTimer.fire()
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift timer with closure:

```
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
         // Do whatever
    }
    timer.fire()
```